# How to download the content of a directory in Azure Storage using az storage fs directory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-storage

Currently, I'm using `az storage blob directory download` but every time I run it, I get: `This command is implicitly deprecated because command group 'storage blob directory' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'az storage fs directory' instead.`

I checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-download) and I can't seem to find what the values for `--file-system` should be. Can someone share an example of downloading the content of a directory (a folder) inside a container inside a blob from Azure Storage to a Windows machine?

Comment: See my answer, I also provide the official documents. :)

Answer (score 2):

--file-system is your container name

```
az storage fs directory download -f myfilesystem --account-name mystorageaccount -s SourceDirectoryPath -d "<local-path>" --recursive
```

Above will download the entire directory

Comment: I have Blob>Container>Directory.. I want to download what's in the directory and not the entire container. is that possible?

Comment: `az storage blob directory download -c MyContainer --account-name MyStorageAccount -s SourceDirectoryPath -d "<local-path>" --recursive` will download the entire directory in a storage container.

`az storage blob directory download -c MyContainer --account-name MyStorageAccount -s "path/to/subdirectory" -d "<local-path>" --recursive`

will download sub dir. AFAIK neither will download the full container just the dir/subdir you specify, failing that you can get azcopy and use that

Comment: Can you please re-read my question? This is what I'm using right now. I'd like to use `az storage fs directory` tool and not `blob directory`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am oversimplifying it, but why not just use pattern:

```bash
az storage blob download-batch --destination "<where you want to download>" --pattern "<directory you want to download from>/*.*" --source "<container name>" --account-name "<storage account>" --account-key "***-key-***"
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch

Hopefully, this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this command:

`az storage fs directory download -f <container name> --account-name <storage account name> -s <the source dir you want to download> -d "./" --recursive --account-key <The access key of the storage account>`

Before run the above command, please make sure your storage account has already enable hierarchical namespace, otherwise the file level of storage account will be flat in your side.

It works on my side:

This is the structure on my side:

[image]

I can download the specific directory to current directory:

[image]

Your can refer to this official document:

[Examples of az storage fs directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-download-examples)

Comment: I get this error `failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: could not list files. Failed with error -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/azbfs.newStorageError, /home/vsts/work/1/s/azbfs/zc_storage_error.go:41
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures) =====
Description=409 This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint., Details: (none)` is this why I need to enable `hierarchical namespace`?